# C#, MS SQL Доступ к данным

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

WinForms создал многопользовательское приложение. Как организовать подключения  к ms sql . то есть для каждого пользователя программы отдельный user_login в ms sql или для всех пользователей программы один user_login в ms sql?
Если user_login в ms sql то как это отразиться на транзакциях?

Answer (score 1):

Видел несколько реализаций клиент-серверной архитектуры в связке WinForms + SQL Server. ВСЕГДА использовался один SQL Server login для доступа к базе. Что в общем-то понятно -- если у вас сотня логинов, то для каждого нужно прописать права например, а пользы от множества логинов никакой. Делается просто табличка [Users] в базе, по которой уже определяется доступ, навешиваются права на сущности итп. Насколько я знаю, на транзакционность это не влияет никак.

Второй момент. Опять же сколько видел реализаций, все делают без транзакций. Т.е. НЕ открывают транзакцию при доступе к базе, по крайней мере, с клиента. Если нужно сделать что-то сложное типа изменения множества объектов сразу -- сделайте хранимую процедуру, откройте/закройте транзакцию в ней.
Причина тут в своеобразной связи между транзакцией и connection, но это уже совсем другая история.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте одного пользователя `MS SQL`, под которым будет происходить работа с БД, и задайте ему необходимые права доступа. Список пользователей вашей программы будет храниться в отдельной таблице вашей БД, т.е. плодить новых пользователей `MS SQL` не надо.

Не совсем понятно почему вас смущает вопрос относительно транзакций. Проблем здесь никаких, ваш сервис, в котором будут осуществляться бизнес операции, будет управлять транзакциями. Здесь вам в помощь паттерн `Unity of Work` и `Repository`.